# Incremental Cipher

Tags: code-golf, cipher

This task is rather simple, and makes use of three distinct "operator" characters. Your task is, given a simple sequence of letters, perform the following task to encode it using `<`,`>`,`*`. You may choose to use either upper or lowercase letters, you do not have to handle both.

---

## Cipher Explanation

The cipher is simple, you're using increment and decrement operations to traverse from letter 1 to the end letter, with `*` being your "submit" function. The operator for "increment" will be `>` and "decrement" will be `<`.

An example using the word `adbc`:

- Start with the first letter of the word, output that letter. `a`
- Next, use `>` and `<` (like brainfuck) to "navigate" the current letter to the next one. `a>` would result in 'raising' `a` by 1 to the letter `b`. `a<` would result in `z` because you're lowering the letter (it wraps, you must always choose the direction resulting in the LEAST number of operations).
- After outputting the correct minimalized combination of `<` and `>` output a `*` to denote that we've reached the next letter.

The steps to encode `adbc` would be:

```
a          # a
a>>>*      # ad
a>>>*<<*   # adb
a>>>*<<*>* # adbc
```

## Examples

The steps to encode `aza` would be:

```
a       # a
a<*     # az
a<*>*   # aza
```

More examples:

```
"abcdef"    =  "a>*>*>*>*>*"
"zyaf"      =  "z<*>>*>>>>>*"
"zzzzzz"    =  "z*****"
"z"         =  "z"
"zm"        =  "z<<<<<<<<<<<<<*" or "z>>>>>>>>>>>>>*" (equidistant)
"zl"        =  "z>>>>>>>>>>>>*"
"alphabet"  =  "a>>>>>>>>>>>*>>>>*<<<<<<<<*<<<<<<<*>*>>>*<<<<<<<<<<<*"
"banana"    =  "b<*>>>>>>>>>>>>>*<<<<<<<<<<<<<*>>>>>>>>>>>>>*<<<<<<<<<<<<<*" OR "b<*<<<<<<<<<<<<<*>>>>>>>>>>>>>*<<<<<<<<<<<<<*>>>>>>>>>>>>>*"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" = "a>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*>*"
"abcdefz"   =  "a>*>*>*>*>*<<<<<<*"
```

## Rules

- We are **encoding** not decoding, so don't mess that up.
- You may assume the message will contain letters `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`, your choice.
- You may use any non-letter/numeric/reserved character to denote `*` (E.G. `$`).
- You must have the ending `*`, it isn't implicit on repeats.
- You may assume no empty strings, but a single character is possible.
- If it is equidistant either way to the next letter, you may choose a direction.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

*Please explain your answer, it helps others learn this way.*

Comment: Just to be clear, the last test case represents `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and is not its own input?

Comment: @NickClifford yes.

Comment: I think `zl` should use `>`.

Comment: Could you please check the examples? `alphabet` is in my opinion `a>>>>>>>>>>>*>>>>*<<<<<<<<*<<<<<<<*>*>>>*<<<<<<<<<<<*` and `zl` should be `z>>>>>>>>>>>>*` and for `banana` should a second solution exists `b<*<<<<<<<<<<<<<*>>>>>>>>>>>>>*<<<<<<<<<<<<<*>>>>>>>>>>>>>*`

Comment: @xnor correct, was a manual typo from `zm`. @jorg good catches, fixed all of them, was a manual effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
OIżN$ẋ"@€⁾><;€⁶ṭḢ
```

Uses a space character in place of `*` (a space, `⁶`, or a newline, `⁷`, saves one byte over `”*`).

Works with *either* uppercase-only *or* lowercase-only input.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/veXSPn8rDXd1KDo@a1jxq3GdnYw1mbHu4c@3DHYv@//@vlJSYB4RKAA)** or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/veXSPn8rDXd1KDo@a1jxq3GdnYw1mbHu4c@3DHYv@H24HciPdKh2Acgpa//9HKyUmJaekpinpKFVVJoIpMAAxQDgXROQAicScgozEpNQSIDMpMQ8IQWJgrekZmVnZObl5@QWFRcUlpWXlFZVVcMkqpVgA) (where those spaces are post-replaced by `*` for reading ease).

#### How?

```
OIżN$ẋ"@€⁾><;€⁶ṭḢ - Main link: string s          e.g. "adbc"
O                 - cast s to ordinals                [97,100,98,99]
 I                - incremental differences           [3,-2,1]
    $             - last two links as a monad:
   N              -     negate                        [-3,2,-1]
  ż               -     zip together                  [[3,-3],[-2,2],[1,-1]]
         ⁾><      - literal ['>','<']                 "><"
      "@€         - using reversed @arguments for €ach zip with("):
     ẋ            -     repeat (-n are like zeros)    [[">>>",""],["","<<"],[">",""]]
            ;€    - concatenate €ach with:
              ⁶   -     literal ' '                   [[">>>","",' '],["","<<",' '],[">","",' ']]
               ṭ  - tack to:
                Ḣ -     head of s (1st char)          [['a'],[">>>","",' '],["","<<",' '],[">","",' ']]
                  - implicit print   (" not printed:) "a>>> << > "
```

Answer (score 11):

## 8086 machine code, <s>70 68</s> 67 bytes

```
00000000  be 82 00 bf 43 01 57 31  d2 ac 3c 0d 74 2c 89 d1  |....C.W1..<.t,..|
00000010  88 c2 aa e3 f4 4f 28 c1  9f 88 e7 79 02 f6 d9 83  |.....O(....y....|
00000020  f9 0d 9f 76 05 83 e9 1a  f6 d9 30 fc 9e b0 3c 78  |...v......0...<x|
00000030  02 b0 3e f3 aa b0 2a aa  eb cf c6 05 24 b4 09 5a  |..>...*.....$..Z|
00000040  cd 21 c3                                          |.!.|
00000043
```

How it works:

```
            |   org 0x100
            |   use16
be 82 00    |       mov si, 0x82        ; source = command line arguments
bf 43 01    |       mov di, result      ; destination = result
57          |       push di
31 d2       |       xor dx, dx          ; clear dx
ac          |   n:  lodsb               ; al = *si++
3c 0d       |       cmp al, 0x0d        ; end of input reached? (newline)
74 2c       |       je q                ; jump to exit in that case
89 d1       |   @@: mov cx, dx          ; store last char in cl
88 c2       |       mov dl, al          ; and store the current char in dl
aa          |       stosb               ; *di++ = al
e3 f4       |       jcxz n              ; skip encoding this char if cx == 0 (only happens for the first char)
4f          |       dec di              ; move di pointer back
28 c1       |       sub cl, al          ; take the difference between this char and the last one
9f          |       lahf                ; store flags from last subtraction in bh
88 e7       |       mov bh, ah
79 02       |       jns @f
f6 d9       |       neg cl              ; make sure cl is positive
83 f9 0d    |   @@: cmp cl, 13          ; which way is shorter?
9f          |       lahf                ; also store these flags
76 05       |       jbe @f
83 e9 1a    |       sub cl, 26          ; invert cl if we're going backwards
f6 d9       |       neg cl
30 fc       |   @@: xor ah, bh          ; xor saved flags together
9e          |       sahf                ; load flags register with the result
b0 3c       |       mov al, '<'
78 02       |       js @f               ; now the sign flag tells us which operator to use
b0 3e       |       mov al, '>'
f3 aa       |   @@: rep stosb           ; while (cx--) *di++ = al
b0 2a       |       mov al, '*'         ; mark the end with an asterisk
aa          |       stosb
eb cf       |       jmp n               ; repeat
c6 05 24    |   q:  mov byte [di], '$'  ; mark end of string
b4 09       |       mov ah, 0x09        ; dos function: print string
5a          |       pop dx              ; dx = string pointer
cd 21       |       int 0x21            ; syscall
c3          |       ret
            |   result rb 0
```

Comment: This. This is beyond cool. You did this REALLY quickly too, dang.

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty much the trivial solution though. Just happens to be quite short in 8086.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 87 bytes

```python
r,*s=input();p=r
for c in s:d=(ord(p)-ord(c)-13)%26-13;r+='<'*d+'>'*-d+'*';p=c
print(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcxLCoAgFEDReauQIJ4fhD7QwHptRBqUEjgxedb6zbiDM7slY4jpfbhYEhJm2@/NdRNzLESW7WB245Hf5HkS@scJPUyiG@fKQgphBekVbCB1RULduCZRiA@jUtrziLX2Aw)

Works with either lowercase or uppercase.

The program builds the output string `r` as it iterates over the characters in the input string. It stores the previous character as `p`, and computes the incrementing operation to get from `p` to the new character `c`.

The interval between the characters is `ord(c)-ord(p)`, and `(ord(c)-ord(p)-13)%26-13` takes it modulo 26 to the interval `[-13..12]`. A negative result means it's shorter to step down, and a positive result means to step up. 
This needs to be converted to a string of `>` or `<` depending on the sign. Rather than using `abs` or a conditional, we take advantage of Python's string multiplication `s*n` giving the empty string when `n` is negative. In the  expression `'<'*-d+'>'*d`, the wrong-signed part does not contribute.

The initial state is handled by splitting the input into its first character and the rest with Python 3's unpacking `r,*s=input()`. The initial character is used to start building the string, as well as the initial "previous" char.

Thanks to ovs for suggesting switching to Python 3 to do this unpacking.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>110</s> 93 bytes

```python
r,*s=input()
b=r
for a in s:d=(ord(a)-ord(b))%26;r+=['>'*d,'<'*(26-d)][d>13]+'*';b=a
print(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#FcUxDoMwDADAPa/IUtkOMEAlhlLzEcTgyFSNVIXIpO9P1VuuWR8uTrl8K5KLbO51mhefsr8eyniaotDwLxLdpnmxjjdYIWgPTwg4zYPSvuk63vcOAiyRxRVLuaJRa/Ipb4lH/QE)

Comment: Ooo... Works for both lower and uppercase, nice one (but I think you can shave off bytes by assuming one or the other).

Comment: Explanation please?

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>118</s> <s>109</s> 107 bytes

The input string is case insensitive.

```js
s=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>(d=~~s-(s=parseInt(c,36)),i)?'<><>'[k=d/13+2|0].repeat([d+26,-d,d,26-d][k])+'*':c)
```

#### How it works

Unlike Python, the JS modulo operator returns a number having the same sign as the dividend rather than the divisor. Also, the JS `repeat()` method throws an error when given a negative number, rather than returning an empty string (and it's significantly longer than a simple `*` anyway).

These are rather unfavorable behaviors for this challenge. So, we'd better identify in which exact case we are rather than relying on math tricks. (Which doesn't mean that such tricks do not exist, but rather that I failed to find them.)

Below is a table describing the 4 possibles cases, where `d` is the signed distance between the current character and the previous one:

```
d           | floor(d / 13) + 2 | direction | repeat
------------+-------------------+-----------+-------
-25 ... -14 |         0         |     <     | d + 26
-13 ... -1  |         1         |     >     | -d  
 +0 ... +12 |         2         |     <     | +d  
+13 ... +25 |         3         |     >     | 26 - d
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>(d=~~s-(s=parseInt(c,36)),i)?'<><>'[k=d/13+2|0].repeat([d+26,-d,d,26-d][k])+'*':c)

console.log(f("abcdef"));
console.log(f("zyaf"));
console.log(f("zzzzzz"));
console.log(f("z"));
console.log(f("zm"));
console.log(f("zl"));
console.log(f("alphabet"));
console.log(f("banana"));
console.log(f("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
console.log(f("abcdefz"));
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 127 Bytes

```
for($l=ord($r=($s=$argn)[0]);$x=ord($s[++$i]);$l=$x)$r.=str_pad("",($a=abs($n=$l-$x))<14?$a:26-$a,"><"[$n>0^$a>13])."*";echo$r;
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d73e527b11efd1d80f81c760bae80a2fccbddf5)

### PHP, 137 Bytes

```
for($l=$r=($s=$argn)[0];$s[++$i];$l=$s[$i])$r.=str_pad("",$d=min($a=abs(ord($l)-ord($s[$i])),$b=26-$a),"><"[$d<$b^$l<$s[$i]])."*";echo$r;
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b58e431502b6c637171aa3a76848a077ffd49c9f)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (lambdabot), <s>161</s> 153 bytes

```
w(s:n)=s:(join.snd$mapAccumL(ap(,).g)s n);g c n|q<-[c..'z']++['a'..c],(Just l,s)<-minimum$first(elemIndex n)<$>[(q,'>'),(reverse q,'<')]=(s<$[1..l])++"*"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#XY9Nb8IwDIbv/AorqpRkLZF2ZQUJbZdNcNqxVFPahhKWj5KktKD9d9YxirTZB7@Pbb2ypW6sC/DCA2cr6cNE/jaerQnOKrZ0znb/m2treHXpiJ8ZOvczsrfSMG@qSPNmWZatXhHekISymnow9KmGEszXIZ1mJWP4jPM4zjDHjJV5Qt5aH0AlnqZTLY3UrY620vlAhBL61VSiHyzSaJGRQ4IXmCbEiaNwXsDAKab5nPg0yh4ZUzmNY/SALppLA3MYrll/ANn0MF1A04b34FYGIughjgHNNgH9iA56OgHIAPGirMQWDZAAOp/4XV5jhLHqUaib4KrZ8UKEGxbcDDnOrtb1Tu4/lTa2OQwPtseuP53/LFwpv3wD)

Explanation:

```
-- Encode a single letter
g c n | q          <- [c..'z']++['a'..c]        -- The alphabet starting from letter c, looping around
      , (Just l,s) <- minimum                   -- Choose the smallest of ..
                    $ first(elemIndex n)        -- the index of the letter n ..
                  <$> [(q,'>'),(reverse q,'<')] -- from the alphabet q and its reverse

      = (s<$[1..l]) -- Repeat < or > the same number of times as the index of n ..
     ++ "*"         -- and append *

-- Encode the whole string
w (s:n) = s                                -- Yield the first char of the input
        : ( join . snd                     -- Concatinate the result of ..
          $ mapAccumL (\a b->(b,g a b))s n -- executing the g function on each letter of the input string ..
                                           -- except the first, passing the previous letter as the 'c' ..
                                           -- argument on each iteration
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>111</s> 103 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>(p=(n+26-(n=parseInt(c,36)))%26,i?'<>'[p+3>>4].repeat(p>13?26-p:p)+'*':c),n=0)
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

```
s=>[...s].map(c=>(n=parseInt(c,36),p&&(p=(n+26-p)%26,s+='><'[p+3>>4].repeat(p>13?26-p:p)+'*'),p=n),s=s[p=0])&&s
```

Originally version that took 111 bytes before I adapted @Arnauld's trick of setting `n` while computing `p`, I think there's probably another trick using `s` instead of `n` but it's getting late so I won't bother.:

Answer (score 2):

### EXCEL VBA 130 bytes

```
s="":p=Mid(s,1,1):For i=1 To Len(s)-1:b=Asc(Mid(s,i+1,1)):a=Asc(Mid(s,i,1)):p=p &String(abs(b-a),IIf(b>a,">","<"))&"*":Next:[a1]=p
```

Run it from Excel VBA Immediate window.

Explanation:

Simple for loop that with String function to repeat the ">" or "<" n number of times where n is the ascii difference between the i and i+1 character string.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 170 bytes

```c
e(c){putchar(c);}i;m(a,b){i=b-a?a>b?b-a<14?b-a:-(a+26-b):a-b<14?-(a-b):b+26-a:0;while(i>0)e(62),i--;while(i<0)e(60),i++;}f(char*l){e(*l);while(l[1])m(*l,l[1]),e(42),l++;}
```

**Detailed** [Live](http://ideone.com/kstNzb)

```c
e(c){ putchar(c); } // encode

g(a,b) // obtain required transition
{
    return (b-a) // calculate distance

         ? (a > b // distance is non-zero

             // if b comes after a
             ? (b-a < 14 // if forward is a shorter path
                 ? b-a // go forward
                 : -(a+26-b)) // otherwise go backward

             // if b comes before a
             : (a-b < 14 // if backward is a shorter path
                 ? -(a-b) // go backward
                 : b+26-a)) // otherwise go forward

         : 0; // if distance is 0
}

// transition
i;m(a,b)
{
    // obtain required transition
    i=g(a,b);

    // encode forward transition
    while(i>0)e('>'), i--;

    // encode backward transition
    while(i<0)e('<'),i++;
}

// incremental cipher function
f(char*l)
{
    e(*l); // encode first character

    while(*(l+1)) // while next character is not END-OF-STRING
        m(*l,*(l+1)), // do transition from current to next character
        e('*'), // encode
        l++; // next
}
```

Comment: Cool solution. The following is probably easier to understand, but 1 byte longer: `#define x q<14?q:q+26
e(c){putchar(c);}i,q;m(a,b){q=b-a;i=q?(a>b?x:-x):0;while(i>0)e('>'),i--;while(i<0)e('<'),i++;}f(char*l){e(*l);while(*(l+1))m(*l,*(l+1)),e('*'),l++;}`

Comment: @Moreaki Thx, but this is a code-golf, so we always aim to reduce byte count, anyway I have added detailed explanation on how my code works.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7-, 232 bytes

```
class C{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{int i=System.in.read(),j,d,c;p(i);while((j=System.in.read())>10){d=(j-i+26)%26;c=d>13?-1:1;while(d%26>0){d-=c;p(61+c);}p(42);i=j;}}static void p(int k){System.out.print((char)k);}}
```

Pretty much the trivial solution. Ungolfed and commented:

```
class C {
    static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        int i = System.in.read(), j, d, c; // i is the last character. j is the current character. d is the difference. c is the direction (-1 is left, 1 is right)
        p(i); // print the starting character first
        while ((j = System.in.read()) > 10) { // keep going until a newline is hit (or an EOF/EOL for -1)
            d = (j - i + 26) % 26; // get the difference (always positive) by wrapping around
            c = d > 13 ? -1 : 1; // get the direction by finding which way is shorter, going right when it's a tie
            while (d % 26 > 0) { // keep going until the current character is reached
                d -= c; // reduce d in the right direction
                p(61 + c); // < is 60 = 61 + (-1), > is 62 = 61 - (-1)
            }
            p(42); // print an asterisk
            i = j; // set the current character to the new reference point
        }
    }

    static void p(int k) {
        System.out.print((char) k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**C++ ,<s>210</s> 190 bytes**

My First Try At Golfing !

```
#include<iostream>
int g(char*a){char k,j,d;std::cout<<*a;a++;for(;*a;a++){for(j=*(a-1),d=j-*a,k=d>0?d>13?62:60:d<-13?60:62;j!=*a;j+=k-61,j=j<97?122:j>122?97:j)std::cout<<k;std::cout<<'*';}}
```

k stores which of < , > or * to print  .At first it simply prints the first element of array then runs a loop for a from first to last element of array . j stores the previous element and then by comparing if j closer to  *a by < or > set k to < ,> respectively and then print k then run this loop until j becomes equal to p . Then after every ending of second loop print * .

Comment: Welcome to the site! If I recall correctly `*p!=0` can be replaced with `*p`.  I'm pretty sure the space in `char *a` is also unnecessary.  You will also need to `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` (although I think it might be cheaper to just add `std::`) to make this a complete answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think you need to include `std::` or `using namespace std;` You'll probably also need `#include <iostream>` in your byte count.

Comment: +1, but do fix the two aforementioned things, welcome to PPCG ;). Checkout some of the languages around the TIO Nexus ( https://tio.run/nexus ) when you get a chance! Maybe introduce yourself to Dennis, he's a key dude floating around here.

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggestions and pointing out the mistakes. I will update the code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
¬sÇ¥v„<>y0›èyÄ×ðJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ASkA1v//wqxzw4fCpXbigJ48Pnkw4oC6w6h5w4TDl8OwSv//YWxwaGFiZWVldA)

**Explanation**

Uses `>`, `<` and `<space>` to denote *increment*, *decrement*, *submit*

```
¬                  # get the first letter of the input string
 sÇ¥               # push a list of delta's of the character codes in the input string
    v              # for each delta
     „<>           # push the string "<>"
        y0›        # check if the delta is positive
           è       # use this to index into the string
            yÄ×    # repeat it abs(delta) times
               ðJ  # join to string with a space
```

Comment: And lost this one by 3 hours .

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>140</s> <s>128</s> <s>129</s> <s>111</s> 113 bytes

I went down a different route to the other JS solutions but it didn't work out too well - here's what I have so far:

```js
f=

([x,...s])=>x+s.map(y=>`<><>`[r=(d=y[c=`charCodeAt`]()-x[c](x=y))/13+2|0].repeat([d+26,-d,d,26-d][r])+`*`).join``

i.addEventListener("input",()=>o.innerText=i.value&&f(i.value))
console.log(f("adbc"))
console.log(f("aza"))
console.log(f("abcdef"))
console.log(f("zyaf"))
console.log(f("zzzzzz"))
console.log(f("z"))
console.log(f("zm"))
console.log(f("zl"))
console.log(f("alphabet"))
console.log(f("banana"))
console.log(f("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
console.log(f("abcdefz"))
```

```html
<input id=i>
<pre id=o>
```

- Saved 12 bytes thanks to a suggestion from [Luke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63774/luke) on destructuring the string.
- Added 1 byte fixing a misreading of the challenge, which I thought allowed for an implicit final print character.
- Saved another 18 bytes thanks to an extensive rewrite by Luke.
- Added 2 bytes as it seems numbers are not valid print characters.

---

### Original, 131 bytes

```js
f=

([x,...s])=>x+s.map(y=>(t=(d=y[c=`charCodeAt`]()-x[c](x=y))<0?-d:d,`<>`[+((r=t<13)&&d>0)||+(!r&&d<0)].repeat(r?t:26-t)+`*`)).join``

i.addEventListener("input",()=>o.innerText=i.value&&f(i.value))
console.log(f("adbc"))
console.log(f("aza"))
console.log(f("abcdef"))
console.log(f("zyaf"))
console.log(f("zzzzzz"))
console.log(f("z"))
console.log(f("zm"))
console.log(f("zl"))
console.log(f("alphabet"))
console.log(f("banana"))
console.log(f("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
console.log(f("abcdefz"))
```

```html
<input id=i>
<pre id=o>
```

Comment: `([x,...s])=>x+s.map(...)` saves 12 bytes. Note that you should append a print character to the end as well. I suggest using a number, which will only cost 2 bytes `\`1\`+1` instead of `\`*\``.

Comment: Thanks, Luke; I'd forgotten I could destructure a string input like that. I must have misread the challenge last night; I could've sworn it said the last print character *was* implicit. Unfortunately, simply tacking it on after the `join` would have resulted in an invalid output for single letter inputs. However, moving the print character within the `map` method only cost 1 byte.

Comment: `([x,...s])=>x+s.map(y=>'<><>'[r=(d=y[c='charCodeAt']()-x[c](x=y))/13+2|0].repeat([d+26,-d,d,26-d][r])+0).join\`\`` for 111 bytes

Comment: Thanks, again, @Luke. Before I edit it in, would you prefer to post the above as your own answer? I feel it differs sufficiently from mine (almost a hybrid of it and Arnauld's) for that to be OK.

Comment: Nah, you can edit it in. I tried golfing a `reduce` solution, but that turned out to be 115 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>167</s> <s>168</s> 126 bytes

```
f=fromEnum
r=replicate
a?b=mod(f a-f b-13)26-13
c#x=r(c?x)'<'++r(-c?x)'>'
s(c,s)x=(x,s++c#x++"*")
e(x:y)=x:snd(foldl s(x,[])y)
```

Now using xnor's arithmetic solution. Call with `e str` where `str :: String` is the string to be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 109 bytes

```hs
a#b=mod(a-b-13)26-13
r=replicate
h(a:b:s)=r(a#b)'>'++r(-a#b)'<'++'*':h(b:s)
h e=""
f(a:r)=a:h(fromEnum<$>a:r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#HYvBCsMgEETvfoWkBTXBQ1voQbK59UPWVFGoJmzt95tNGRiGx5uOFw9le2u03t4e5v7kFgQU9k9esQWRNDrvvgZIs2vUoqaJtP3vmbcalUv6NESSAYZBRH6QAWQcaSuv@ivzdTlZL5irBJlrC4Rrk7F7rJwD) Uses [xnor's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116843/56433). Call with `f "somestring"`.